# Unity Iterate over a list to sort by the number value

Tags: list, unity-game-engine, streamreader, streamwriter

I have a text file called highscore.txt and I know the format of the data going into the file which works in the following way:

```
Username:score
```

I then need to search through the whole file to see where the new score needs to be added such that the file is in order of score from largest to smallest

```
    List<string> tempoaryList = new List<string>();
    List<int> valueList = new List<int>();
    string lineValues = "";

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(finalPath))
    {
        while (sr.EndOfStream == false)
        {
            lineValues = sr.ReadLine();
            tempoaryList.Add(lineValues);
            int data = Convert.ToInt32(lineValues.Substring(lineValues.LastIndexOf(':') + 1));
            valueList.Add(data);
        }

    }
    valueList.Sort();
    for(int i =0; i > valueList.Count; i++)
    {
        if(valueList[i] <= playerScore)
        {
            tempoaryList.Insert(i - 1, playerScore.ToString());
        }
    }
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(finalPath, false))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tempoaryList.Count; i++)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(tempoaryList[i]);
            Debug.Log(tempoaryList[i]);
        }
    }
```

The above just simply doesn't change the text file and leaves it as it was found, any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your code to this:

**ScoreList.cs**

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ScoreList : MonoBehaviour {

    private void Start() {
        GameOver.GameOverEvent += UpdateScoreBoardFile;
    }

    private void UpdateScoreBoardFile(string playerName, int playerScore) {
        string lineValues;
        string finalPath = "[ScoreBoard File Location]";
        List<string> tempoaryList = new List<string>();
        List<int> valueList = new List<int>();
        bool isScoreLowest = true;

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(finalPath)) {
            while (sr.EndOfStream == false) {
                lineValues = sr.ReadLine();
                tempoaryList.Add(lineValues);
                int data = Convert.ToInt32(lineValues.Substring(lineValues.LastIndexOf(':') + 1));
                valueList.Add(data);
            }
        }

        if (tempoaryList != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < valueList.Count; i++) {
                if (valueList[i] <= playerScore) {
                    tempoaryList.Insert(i, playerName + ":" + playerScore.ToString());
                    isScoreLowest = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (isScoreLowest) {
            tempoaryList.Add(playerName + ":" + playerScore.ToString());
        }

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(finalPath, false)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < tempoaryList.Count; i++) {
                sw.WriteLine(tempoaryList[i]);
                Debug.Log(tempoaryList[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**GameOver.cs** (or wherever you manage the game over condition):

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class GameOver : MonoBehaviour {

    public static event Action<string, int> GameOverEvent;
    string playerName;
    int finalScore;

    private void GameOver() {
        //Do other stuff when the game is over
        GameOverEvent(playerName, finalScore);
    }
}
```

Explanation of the changes:

`isScoreLowest` is needed to `Add` the new lowest score at the end of the list, since the `for` loop won't add it by itself.

The `if (tempoaryList != null)` check is done to skip the `for` loop when the scoreboard is empty.

And you saved yourself from doing a `Sort`, which is always a good thing. :)

Comment: Thanks for that, is there any way to also prevent there being multiple entries when adding as it produces roughly 30 extra lines in the file. Suspect this is due to being called in update() which it has to be.

Comment: You should use a simple `event` to handle the update of the scoreboard, fired when the game is over. I'll edit my answer to add the code to show how it's done.

Comment: Even with the Event system it still creates multiple instances, is this due to the way I call the event in the update method?

Comment: I'd say yes, but it'd be better if you edit your question by adding the relevant `Update()` code.